# Opencv Square detection in image and take this image

Tags: opencv, detection

i am new about opencv. I have too much image and i have to take images in square. You can see below

[image]

How can take this image ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look [very simple article](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/).

Main idea: find contours, smooth them, find out how many vertices has each of them.

***BUT*** maybe you will need to do more complex preprocessing, because *image* may have rectangles inside it.